# Access is denied after deploying while accessing Google Drive Api

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, google-api, google-oauth

Developing MVC application with Google OAuth to access drive API. While I was accessing Google API in the development environment it works just fine. But when I deploy it in IIS or Shared hosting it shows access denied with below exception.

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]


 System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +602
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +60
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<ReceiveCodeAsync>d__14.MoveNext() +265

[NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=1062976495544-dg9ak1e6uovp7p6gmlf1vcqvvq6mnefv.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:7862%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https:%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive" for authorization. See inner exception for details.]
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<ReceiveCodeAsync>d__14.MoveNext() +1029
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<AuthorizeAsync>d__8.MoveNext() +730
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<AuthorizeAsync>d__4.MoveNext() +571
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext() +438
```

Things I have tried :

1. Verify Domain in google dev console.
2. Change protocol from HTTP to
   https

Comment: It is not google that is denying access. It is windows. It denies "access" to starting a Process from your app. I guess your Service is running with some rights missing.

Comment: @Khaled have you tried https://forums.iis.net/t/1183222.aspx

Comment: i think so. but how to identify what is missing. any suggestion would be appreciated :)

Comment: @Md.AlimUlKarim i tried that. no improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article helped me to resolve this issue:
[Implementing OAuth2.0 Authorization For Google In ASP.NET](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-oauth2-0-authorization-for-google-in-asp-net/?fbclid=IwAR3vlyKeFoiEcZ2zt_qhOP8rKXkYWUlhEPTgiCWGA8FId7MlRC6h4DG0wE0).

How it works (by article):

- 1. Create Web Server client_secret.json.
- 2. GetAuthorizationUrl() - create url for get toke **temporary token**.
- 3. Redirect to GoogleCallback() and get **refresh and access tokens** using ExchangeAuthorizationCode().
- 4. Save them to the file `"~/Resources/driveApiCredentials/drive-credentials.json/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-{account}"`.
- 5. Use this saved tokens.

After that just use google authentication for drive:

```
     // Client for requests
    private DriveService client;
    
    // Class constructor
    public GoogleDrive(string account)
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        Login = account;
        
        // Load Web Secret file
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($"~/Resources/client_secret_{account}.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // Path to token folder 
            string credPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Resources/driveApiCredentials", "drive-credentials.json"));

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                account,
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            //Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to folder: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = account,
        });

        client =  service;
    }
```

This code use tokens loaded before for initialize `DriveService`.

Comment: What do you pass to "account" variable

Comment: @irfandar "account" - it's the name for google account to storing it on the disk (in my case - account login (without @ and others symbols after it)). Search for "account" word in my code.

Comment: This solutions is not working in dot net core. Have you any solutions for dot net core 3.1